# R Shiny: Dashboard Body does not change, when I use Widgets with Select Input

Tags: r, render, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard with multiple tabs in the side bar and the dashboard body is dependent on these tabs. There is 1 select input in the 1 Tab. But the dashboard Body is not changing when I click on the Tabs. I have tried few attempts with "updatetabitems", but all in vain. Many thanks in advance!

Following is a sample reference code

```
##UI

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
sidebar= dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"),
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("options",label=h5("Select Column"),""))),
  menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("th"),
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("options",label=h5("Select Column"),"")))
  )
)

body=  dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
          fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))
          )
  ),
  # Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "m2",selected=TRUE,
          h2("Widgets tab content")
  )
)
)
dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title= "city"),sidebar,body)


##Server
server <- function(input, output) {
outputplot1= renderPlot({
})
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do, the provided example shows empty dashboard with no data. To start with, I think the `outputplot1` should be preceded by `output`, so `output$outputplot1= renderPlot({
})`

Comment: so there is only place holders for dashboard body and I want to see them changed, when I clicking on the tabs in the side bar.. but its not happening